# How do I use Tensorflow for signal processing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, signal-processing, deep-learning

I have recently started learning about CNN and tensorflow(still a beginner). I am trying to train a simple convolutional neural to identify my randomly generated exponential signals , from their tau(time constant) value.

My question is how to assign them into classes and get tensorflow to learn from this data?

The code I used for generating the signals is below-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

lorange= 1
hirange= 10
amplitude= random.uniform(-10,10)
t= 10
random.seed()
tau=random.uniform(lorange,hirange)
x=np.arange(t)

plt.xlabel('t=time')
plt.ylabel('x(t)')
plt.plot(x, amplitude*np.exp(-x/tau))
plt.show()
```

Comment: How cool that you're doing signal processing with Tensorflow or deep-learning in Tensorflow. On my github, I have three repo's for signal processing with Tensorflow. That might be a good start to code from. I am open to your input. Reach me over email * [Music genre classification with CNN](http://robromijnders.github.io/cnn_music/) * [Time-series classification with LSTM's in Tensorflow](http://robromijnders.github.io/LSTM_tsc/) * [Time-series classification with CNN's](http://robromijnders.github.io/CNN_tsc/)